# Multi key in redis by spring boot

Tags: spring, redis

`redisTemplate.opsForHash().get ("CAR", name);`

so we get the car by name.

`redisTemplate.opsForHash ().put ("CAR", "TOYOTA", "PRIUS");`

This is how we write data to REDIS.
That is, using TOYOTA and CAR we can get PRIUS.

Now, I should understand how to record and find data by a pair of keys. For example, I should find a car not only by brand ("TOYOTA") but also by color.

`redisTemplate.opsForHash () .put (" CAR "," TOYOTA "+" WHITE "," PRIUS ");`

The question is how to use the second parameter?

`redisTemplate.opsForHash (). get (" CAR ", name + color);`

In my case, the pair name and color are unique and i need to search for them.

**In case of searching by one value, everything works fine, but it is not clear how to search by two parameters**.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just maintian different cars and cars with colors in the hash.

```
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("TOYOTA","PRIUS");
    map.put("TOYOTA:WHITE","PRIUS-w");
    map.put("TOYOTA:YELLOW","PRIUS-y");
    redisTemplate.opsForHash().putAll("CAR",map);
```